# How to fix MongoDB connection error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, cors

I'm getting a cors error when trying to login into my MERN app
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnibF.png).It's working fine locally and in the Network tab it shows a 503 error code.

My Heroku logs show these messages.

*const err = new MongooseError(message);*

*MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms*

But, I'm getting the '**User *Name* verified**' console log in the Heroku logs which is present in the **validation.js** file below. So the backend connection is fine I think.

I used **0.0.0.0/0** in MongoDB network access and used ***cors*** package for all origin.
Also tried using ***mongoose.connect*** using **async/await**, and using the older drivers in MongoDB but nothing seems to work. If anyone knows how to fix it please respond.
Here is my code in node.js.

index.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const DBConnect = require('./mongo')
const Login = require('./routes/login')
const Google = require('./routes/google')
const Register = require('./routes/register')
const SaveData = require('./routes/saveData')
require('dotenv').config()

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

const app = express()

const corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    optionSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(express.json())

DBConnect().then(()=>console.log('DB Connection successfull!'))

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{ res.json('Server running')})
app.use('/api/gauth', Google)
app.use('/api/login', Login)
app.use('/api/register', Register)
app.use('/api/save', SaveData)

app.listen(port,()=>console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`))
```

mongo.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

module.exports = async () => {

    const username = process.env.USER_NAME
    const password = process.env.PASSWORD
    const cluster = process.env.CLUSTER
    const dbname = process.env.DB_NAME
    const url = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@${cluster}.mongodb.net/${dbname}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
    const mongooseOptions = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    }

    await mongoose.connect(url, mongooseOptions)
    .then(x => console.log(`Connected to MongoDB : ${x.connections[0].name}`))
    .catch(err => console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err))
}
```

google.js

```js
const app = require('express')()
const googleAuth = require('../components/validation')
const userModel = require('../components/models')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken')

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

app.post('/', async (req,res)=>{

    const user = await googleAuth(req.body.token)
    const emailExist = await userModel.findOne({ email: user.email })

    const token = JWT.sign({_id: user.id}, process.env.TOKEN_KEY)
    
    const data = {
        token: token,
        email: user.email,
        name: user.name,
        image: user.image,
        data: emailExist && emailExist.data || []
    }

    if(!emailExist){
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
        const cipherPass = await bcrypt.hash(user.id, salt)

        const newUser = new userModel({
            username: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            password: cipherPass,
            image: user.image,
            data: []
        })

        try{
            await newUser.save()
            res.status(200).json(data)
        }catch (err){
            res.status(500).json(err)
        }
    }else{
        res.status(200).json(data)
    }
})

module.exports = app
```

validation.js

```js
const { OAuth2Client } = require('google-auth-library')
const client = new OAuth2Client(process.env.OAUTH_ID)

const googleAuth = async token => {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: token,
        audience: process.env.OAUTH_ID
    })

    const payload = ticket.getPayload()
    // console.log('Paylod:', payload)

    console.log(`User ${payload.name} verified`)

    const { sub, name, email, picture } = payload
    const userId = sub

    return { id:userId, name:name, email:email, image:picture}
}

module.export = googleAuth
```

Comment: You're hitting the so-called "wildcard exception". See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: I think it is a MongoDB authentication issue, plz check once your MongoDB is able to connect from the server or anywhere.  not a cors error as per you mention here if your API call is working and the server give an error

Comment: for cors error try to replace variable **corsOptions**


`const corsOptions = {
  
}`

in index.js

OR replace **app.use(cors(corsOptions))** to `app.use(cors())`

Comment: I already tried using my front end address as origin instead of the '*' wildcard and also tried removing the corsOptions variable, I only added it to specifically add methods just to check if it works that way but no luck. I can connect to MongoDB if I use the backend locally. Only when I hosted it the 503 err comes.